# MS Access VBA, SQL Script: In(), <>, AND syntaxes

Tags: sql, vba, select, where-clause

I have a script I need to show the genres and filter out nulls.

```
ReturnBooks = "Select * from [Books] where ([Type] IN ('B','K' ,'R' ,'C') AND [Type] <> 'No' AND [BookGenre] IS NOT NULL)) Order By [LName] ASC"
```

I need the BookGenre to be not null but the syntax returns nothing. Originally the code did not have that line and it did return some results.

```
ReturnBooks = "Select * from [Books] where ([Type] IN ('B','K' ,'R' ,'C') AND [Type] <> 'No') Order By [LName] ASC"
```

Which returns the type of book.

How might I fit the IS NOT NULL in the script?

For example books table would return an author by last name depending on the genre. I also get a datatype mismatch from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disbalance of parentheses in your query.

And you need to show some sample data from you table in your database.

Comment: Yes, thank you for noticing that. That was not only why though, that was a typo I missed after cleaning up an experiment with the script. Even with that correction it won't work as it is. I will make another edit shortly.

Comment: You need to show your table description and some sample data. For now try this: ReturnBooks = "Select * from [Books] where ([Type] IN ('B','K' ,'R' ,'C') AND [Type] <> 'No' AND [BookGenre] IS NOT NULL) Order By [LName] ASC"

Comment: Ok. I prefer not to disclose private data. I hope you understand.

Comment: These are all string/text.

Comment: Ok. Try ReturnBooks = "Select * from [Books] where ([Type] IN ('B','K' ,'R' ,'C') AND [Type] <> 'No' AND [BookGenre] <> NULL) Order By [LName] ASC

Comment: You got it right! The IS NOT NULL would not agree with the other syntaxes in the complex of script elements. The <> syntax works better than IS NOT here.

Comment: Yes. It became clear when you pointed out that you were working with ms access. Always mention tags exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check you where clause:
**([Type] IN ('B','K' ,'R' ,'C') AND [Type] <> 'No')** AND **[BookGenre] IS NOT NULL))**

If your [Type] in ('B','K' ,'R' ,'C') then it would never be 'No', so, the "And Type <> 'No'" is no use.

"IS NOT NULL" phare works well with mysql, sqlserver.

If you only just need the records that BookGenre is not null, just use this:

```
ReturnBooks = "SELECT * FROM [Books] WHERE [BookGenre] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [LName] ASC"
```

If you need to filter the record with BookGenre is blank as well, try this:

```
ReturnBooks = "SELECT * FROM [Books] WHERE ([BookGenre] IS NOT NULL) AND ([BookGenre] <> '')  ORDER BY [LName] ASC"
```

Hoped this may help you.

Comment: This is MS Access VBA... I should add that in my edits. It is assigning the SQL to a variable.

Comment: How would you do it with the In criteria, which group the books then not including the 'No' string which is shorthand not illustrated. And the book genre is not null.

Comment: Let make clear you need: You need the list of books that meet two criterias:

1. Type is not equal to 'No' and

2. BookGenre is Not NULL.

Is this right?

Comment: I got an answer, look above.